# How to reduce n-gram features?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-processing, sentiment-analysis, n-gram

I have been dealing with a problem in Text processing. I would appreciate if anyone could help me.
I have dataset consisting 12,000 record of comments.
When I run n-gram extractor on this, I gain 170,000 unique unigram + bigram which is so many that it takes too long to be processed by machine learning algorithm.

How should I reduce the number of these extracted features? Is there any especial algorithm or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to keep all the N-grrams.  You should be trimming the list of N-grams by frequency.  For example, only consider unigrams that occur 40 or more times.  The cut-off for trimming bi-grams will be lower.  It will be lower still for tri-grams and so on and so on.